# preventing a position absolute from passing a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I positioned a footer to the bottom of a div but it keeps overlapping the buttons on mobile. is there any way to block the footer when it hits another div.my code is as follows `position:absolute; bottom: 0`

Comment: Why are you absolute positioning your footer? I'm assuming you're trying to implement a sticky footer? Here's a much better technique: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: The example you gave me worked well but when trying to adjust the height of the site-footer it just went nuts

Comment: That's because you have to adjust the margins/padding to be the same as the height of the footer, that's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to help you if you provide us with the whole code. Anyway you can using margin-top or z-index property to solve your problem.

**margin-top**
You can keep a fixed distance between your footer and the div adjacent to it. So that they will never touch each other.

**z-index**
Another way is to take your footer in the background. So that it won't overlap the buttons. Instead, buttons will overlap it and won't get hidden.

Comment: its position absolute so margin wont help much. All I need help with is preventing a position absolute div from overlapping another

Comment: Use max-height property for the above div as such that it won't collide with the footer.